# How to access post meta on the first time a post is published

Tags: post-meta

Am trying to send an email based on the contents of a post published but it should only be done if its the first time the post is published.

Therefore am using `add_action( 'transition_post_status', [ $this, 'jackie_publish_post_hook'], 20, 3 );`

the callback function `jackie_publish_post_hook` has the following content.(The full content is quite big and some information is irrelevant to this question therefore i will only include the relative part)

`public function jackie_publish_post_hook($new,$old,$post){`

...

```
$accepted = array('pending','future','draft','auto-draft');
if(in_array($old, $accepted) && $new == 'publish'){
    $attachment = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full', true);
    print_r($attachment);
}
```

My problem occurs when I try to access the any post meta eg the featured image or any custom field as they have not been saved yet to database.

Some solutions have suggested using `add_action( 'publish_post', ... );` and then accessing the values from the `$_POST` variable but when I do this the `$_POST` returns an empty array.
I have confirmed from the developers tools that the featured image id is being sent as a post parameter with the request but I cannot seem to access it from the given callback.
[image: The POST Request parameters from the browser side]

If I force the function to run after a post has been published earlier it returns the correct data. ie running manually.
`$this->jackie_publish_post_hook('publish','draft',get_post(70801));`

Is there a special way to access the first time submitted data from the hook callback function or what am I doing wrong?

Can I access the post meta from unsaved but submitted data to wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

I usually handle this with [save_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/) action.

```
// We'll use 1000, low priority (we'll let other hooks to run first)
add_action( 'save_post', [$this, 'jackie_publish_post_hook'], 1000, 3 );
```

Then within your class:

```
function jackie_publish_post_hook( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    if ( $update ) return false; // Post already existed, don't proceed

    // Do stuff
}
```

Or use a post meta:

```
function jackie_publish_post_hook( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    if ( get_post_meta( $post_id, 'jackie_post_processed', true ) != '' ) return false;
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'jackie_post_processed', 1 );

    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if( $update ) return false;`

Comment: Also the update is return true even on first publish so I do not think this is the way to go.

Comment: @domii you're right, it's `if ( $update ) return false;`. I have noticed that `save_posts` is triggered several times when you create a new post, however for the very first trigger it's guaranteed that `$update = false`.